# How are Solana transaction fees involving invoke calculated?

Tags: transactions, cpi, fees

In the code example taken from [here](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/cross-program-invocation/native/programs/lever/src/lib.rs#L57) we see the following invocation:

```
    invoke(
        &system_instruction::create_account(
            &user.key,
            &power.key,
            lamports_required,
            account_span as u64,
            program_id,
        ),
        &[
            user.clone(), power.clone(), system_program.clone()
        ]
    )?;
```

Question is, who signs for this transaction? My guess will be the original signer who signed for the transaction that called the program from which the cross program invocation is being made. Is this correct?

If so, how then is the transaction fee for this CPI calculated? And who pays for it?

Answer (score 1):

looking at the code it looks like the new program account and the users wallet will be signers and the owner will be the program. So the keypair calling it will be able to change the account data I think. Paying for the rent exemption of the new account (lamports field) and the transaction fees will be also the caller of the transaction. In this case "user"

```
  public static TransactionInstruction CreateAccount(
  PublicKey fromAccount,
  PublicKey newAccountPublicKey,
  ulong lamports,
  ulong space,
  PublicKey programId)
{
  List<AccountMeta> accountMetaList = new List<AccountMeta>()
  {
    AccountMeta.Writable(fromAccount, true),
    AccountMeta.Writable(newAccountPublicKey, true)
  };
  return new TransactionInstruction()
  {
    ProgramId = SystemProgram.ProgramIdKey.KeyBytes,
    Keys = (IList<AccountMeta>) accountMetaList,
    Data = SystemProgramData.EncodeCreateAccountData(programId, lamports, space)
  };
}

internal static byte[] EncodeCreateAccountData(PublicKey owner, ulong lamports, ulong space)
{
  byte[] data = new byte[52];
  data.WriteU32(0U, 0);
  data.WriteU64(lamports, 4);
  data.WriteU64(space, 12);
  data.WritePubKey(owner, 20);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: "There is no new signer, because the account will be owned by the program" okay maybe in this example that is the case? what if a CPI involves setting the owner to another program? What happens then? Can `invoke` still be used?

Comment: I checked the link to the solanacookbook. That seems to be about PDA. Not sure the example linked to in my question is about PDAs though

Comment: The link you shared uses `invoke_signed` which I understand comes to play when working with PDAs. The code in my question uses `invoke` which is not about PDAs. So I am not sure your explanation clears the air :/

Comment: Oh sorry i was too quick on that, didnt read properly.

Comment: I updated the answer, maybe it helps now?

Comment: i still have questions. The transaction fee is calculated and payed with the first call. This is a second call, that is it is a CPI. How can the fee for this CPI be calculated and known before hand when calculating the fee for the first transaction?

Comment: The cost to make the account rent exempt can be calculated with RpcClient.GetMinimumBalanceForRentExemptionAsync(accountSize) so with that you can calculate the cost to create the account. If with Transaction fee you mean the 0.000005 sol then this only needs to be paid once per transaction not per instruction.